# Question Title as Placeholder - SURVEYJS CREATOR

Tags: vue.js

**What is the current behavior?**
Currently need to backspace the question title and then re-type the new question again

**What is the expected behavior?**
Placeholder as question title and need not to backspace it (When creating survey questions, the placeholder text should be PLACEHOLDER text that is automatically overwritten when the user clicks in to edit the question title)

Heres my code:

```
[
  {
    "name": "page1",
    "elements": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "title": "Enter question text here...",
        "choices": [
          "item1",
          "item2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Dhara Parmar, welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you provide more details with an usage code example?

Comment: @Francis Rodrigues 
pages: [
          {
            name: 'page1',
            elements: [
              {
                type: 'checkbox',
                title: 'Enter question text here...',
                choices: ['item1', 'item2'],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],  
  Currently above is the type of question for checkbox, where the title is 'Enter question text here..' & my requirement is to have title as placeholder & want to immediately start typing the question title, instead of clicking on question and backspacing it for typing new question title